# how to get date object from a JSONObject

Tags: java, date, json

My JSON object looks like

```
{"iso":"2014-01-01T21:13:00.000Z","__type":"Date"}
```

I need to get the date from it as a date Object.
What I have tried-

```
String dateStr = JsonObject.getString("iso"); //output is 2014-01-01T21:13:00.000Z
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date birthDate = sdf.parse(dateStr);
```

but this doesnt work, firstly it prompts me to add a try/catch which I do. When the debugger comes to Date birthDate = sdf.parse(dateStr); it just skips this.

How do I get a date out of my JSON object?

Comment: Thats because your date format does not match the string you get.

Comment: *i just skips this*.  The only way it "skips" it is if you have a try/catch without any exception handling (i.e. empty catch block.)  You should make sure you are dumping the stacktrace and taking heed to what it says (assuming it does get an exception).

Comment: @Henry yeah I understand that the date format isnt matching, but there is a T in between and a Z at the end, how do I get rid of them?

Comment: You can try something like this: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a date format like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
```

to match the input string format.

For details, consult the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

For example this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String dateStr = "2014-01-01T21:13:00.000Z";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
    Date birthDate = sdf.parse(dateStr);
    System.out.println(birthDate);
}
```

prints (actual output depends on your time zone)

> Wed Jan 01 22:13:00 CET 2014

Comment: I am getting the error java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2014-01-01T21:13:00.000Z" (at offset 23)

Comment: it says E/AndroidRuntime(26444): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'X'

Comment: Should it make a difference since I am working on an android device?

Comment: Ah, you should have mentioned that you are on Android. It does not have the `X` format character. Maybe `z` works, but I am not sure. See http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: I am so sorry, I didnt know that android is any different than native java, anyways it worked! as you said I had to do yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'

Comment: If you match the Z literally, you may have to handle the time zone manually.